# How to get rid of unwanted whitespace when collapsing TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with cells that expand/collapse when users tap on them, using:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  ...
  [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
  ...
}
```

After the reloadRowsAtIndexPath is run, I have heightForRowAtIndexPath return a different height depending on whether the cell is collapsing or expanding:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // if expand
  return 200;
  // if collapse
  return 49;
}
```

When I collapse a cell at the bottom of the table, the table shrinks, but it is brought down way too far, leaving a significant amount of whitespace at the top of the table. I've tried `[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` after calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, which solves the problem, but that makes the table jumpy. It would go down too far leaving whitespace then jump back to the top. How can I shrink the table cell without making it scroll down too far?

Answer (score 0):

After you change something that affects tableView height, you can use these code to update cell height without reloading the table:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I tried calling those 2 functions before and after calling reloadRowsAtIndexPath but they don't seem to make a difference. I think it's cause reloadRowsAtIndexPath spins up a new thread and [tableView endUpdates] is run before the thread finishes. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Don't reload the row when you are using these methods.

Comment: I just looked at the docs again and it seems like beginUpdates & endUpdates only need to be called when inserting/deleting rows. It doesn't they're needed to change cell height.

Comment: Yes, but it also works when your table rows have something changes to make tableview render immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a `UIView` animation in main thread to avoid this,such as:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }];
});
```

Then try:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0;
    self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0;
    self.tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0;
    self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentAutomatic;
}
```

Comment: I tried calling this after `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths]` but it's still jumpy after collapsing the cell

Comment: @TienPhan Edited my answer.Please have a look.